# Typescript interface for a Functional Component that requires children

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I typically define my functional react components with the following pattern:

```
interface Props {
    title: string; //for example
}

export const MyComponent : React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
    const {
        title, 
        children //This is implied as allowed by the FunctionalCompoment interface I believe

    } = props; 

     return <div>{title}{children}</div> 
}
```

I have a component that *must* have children, as a lot of react components do.

How do I enforce this?

On a related note, is it possible to enforce that the children must of a certain kind of React component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the built in way but children are optional in this type.

```
export const MyComponent : React.FunctionComponent<React.PropsWithChildren<Props>> = (props) => {
  const {
    title,
    children //This is implied as allowed by the FunctionalCompoment interface I believe

  } = props;

  return <div>{title}{children}</div>
}
```

I would suggest creating your own type or interface

```
type MustHaveChildren<T> = T & { children: ReactNode }
```

or

```
interface MustHaveChildren {
 children: ReactNode
}

interface T extends MustHaveChildren {
 .... // your types
}
```

**Usage:**

Type

```
export const MyComponent : React.FunctionComponent<MustHaveChildren<Props>> = 
  (props) => (...)
```

Interface

```
export const MyComponent : React.FunctionComponent<Props> = 
  (props) => (...)
```

Comment: Children are optional in that definition. This is not convoluted. You need to work on your coding skills if you think this is convoluted. This is exactly how it is defined in the typings except with a question mark, which makes it optional. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/0bb8e0ea9788b97ab9e569f9c55cc01e2a069520/types/react/index.d.ts#L759